# Git Templates not Found on Cloning but on Creating

Tags: git, templates, git-config

I've got the warning `templates not found /OurServer/SomeDirectory/GitTemplate` after setting the template-Path manually. When i look into the repo, the hooks, which are in the template, doesn't exist. But when i create a new repo all the hooks get copied.

The Path is a Networkpath:
In Windows: \\OurServer\SomeDirectory\GitTemplate
Entry in systemwide gitconfig:

```
[init]
    templatedir = "//OurServer/SomeDirectory/GitTemplate"
```

Interesting is the difference between the Path set in the config :`//OurServer` and in the error `/OurServer`.

If i change it to

```
[init]
    templatedir = "///OurServer/SomeDirectory/GitTemplate"
```

cloning works, but then creation shows the error `templates not found ///OurServer/SomeDirectory/GitTemplate`

I Use git 2.13 on Windows 7 with mingw.

Has anybody a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you map the network drive to a drive letter and configure that drive instead of the network path directly, it will work.

This seems to be a bug, you should report it to the Git mailing list which is the official way to report bugs.